# git remote command output message

Tags: git, github

I use git remote command to display remote branches, and it displays output:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@code.csdn.net:spider119/mygridview.git (fetch)
origin  git@code.csdn.net:spider119/mygridview.git (push)
```

I don't understand that why remote branches display like above, it seems they are the same branches. And I see othes people's command output was like:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@code.csdn.net:spider119/mygridview.git
```

what's the differences of the output means? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different repository as the push-target for each remote, useful when you fork a repository you have read-only access. You can see the [Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Dictator-and-Lieutenants-Workflow), for example, that is the one used for the Linux Kernel development.

In that case, you don't have write access to the blessed repositories, so you always fetch from one and push to another.

From [git-remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
set-url
Changes URL remote points to. Sets first URL remote points to matching regex <oldurl> (first URL if no <oldurl> is given) to <newurl>. If <oldurl> doesn’t match any URL, error occurs and nothing is changed.

With --push, push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs.
```

As for the difference in messages, it mostly has to be with any minor version change, or a minor setting that toggles between them - I don't think that's important at all, but feel free to do a little research if it annoys you.